# How do I create an event on a different form within the VB .NET application for the same device?

Tags: vb.net, handler

I'm working on a POS program where I have a POS keyboard COM control within the application.  When I double click the icon, an Event is created:

---

```
Private Sub PosKeyboard_DataEvent(sender As Object, e As AxOposPOSKeyboard_CCO._IOPOSPOSKeyboardEvents_DataEventEvent) Handles PosKeyboard.DataEvent

 If PosKeyboard.POSKeyData = 1 Then Exit_Button.PerformClick()

 End Sub**
```

---

How do I create an event on a different form within the app for the same device?

Comment: If you want to write good code, you wouldn't.  If you explain the relationship between the forms then we can provide the best advice about how to communicate between them.

Comment: The app starts with a form called "HW", all my point of sales devices are created on this form for the cash drawers, scanners, etc.   I open, enable the devices for use.  The pos keyboard has a data event when I push a button it triggers a click of a "Exit" button that takes me to the "Login Screen" .  From there I want to generate a event for the POS keyboard defined in the HW screen on the login screen and other screens in the future. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Is `PosKeyboard` a control on the `HW` form or is it an object that provides an abstraction of a physical keyboard?

Comment: its an object.  But since it is  POS keyboard it is not recognized like an HID keyboard where I can just use the Keydown option. Hope that helps

Comment: Then why is there a problem at all?  Why can't you simply pass the object to the other form and handle its even there same as always?

Comment: Most of the devices I refer to the HW form from the form I'm working into to code for the device.  For instance if I'm in the "Main Form" and I select the button that says No Sale the I would then send a command that says HW.cashdrawer1.opendrawer.   The dataevent appears in the HW for the keyboard but I really do not want to have to code all my forms under one HW form because it becomes quite confusing.  This just a hobby for me so I'm sorry if I don't always understand what your referring to.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments so far, I will provide an answer that I think applies.

When it comes to handling events, you have a variable to which you assign an object and then you handle an event of that variable.  When the assigned object raises its event, the handling method is executed.  So, in your case, you need to start by declaring a variable in the form in which you want to handle the event, e.g.

```
Private WithEvents posKeyboard As SomeType
```

The `WithEvents` keyword is required for that variable to be able to be used in a `Handles` clause.  I use `SomeType` because I don't know the actual type of your object, although I suspect that it's something like `_IOPOSPOSKeyboard`.

You can then write a method to handle the desired event, copying the signature from your other form:

```
Private Sub posKeyboard _DataEvent(sender As Object, e As AxOposPOSKeyboard_CCO._IOPOSPOSKeyboardEvents_DataEventEvent) Handles posKeyboard .DataEvent
    '...
End Sub
```

You then need to pass in the object that will be raising the event from the other form, which you can do via a parameter in a constructor or some other method or a property setter.

Comment: I understand what you are saying about the declaring the system in each form.  Well at least I think that is what you are referring to.  This is what I was trying to avoid. For each form I do this I would have to open the device, so it like basically a new device.  Im trying to avoid disabling and closing the device with each form.  The HW screen is always open in the background it just not visible.   Any further advice?

Comment: No you don't have to open the device for each form.  No it's not s new device.  Listen to what I'm saying.  You declare a variable in each form.  A variable is just a variable, nothing more.  You then pass the existing object from one for to the other and assign it to the variable.  A variable and an object are two different things.  If there is only one object then you only open the device once.  You can assign that same object to a thousand variables if you like but it's still just one object.  Tell me, are you father's wife, your mother and your cousin's aunt three different people?